# Run python script with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have an .sh file which spawns a simple http server with python3. What I need is to successfully run this file with Jenkins. The job goes "green" but the directory I try to serve with python http server is not available and the browser says "Request failed". `ps -a` also does not show any python process.

When I run the python command directly on the console the server gets started and `ps -a` shows the pid of python process. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the user which run jenkins? Do you put in script python server to run in background?

Comment: The user which runs Jenkins is not the user which runs the script on console and yes I put the python server command to the background with `&> /dev/null &` Can this be the cause?

Comment: Do the user which run jenkins have permissions to see/run the shell and/or python script?

Comment: Tbh I don't know. How can I lookup this?

Comment: `ls -l <shell script> <python script> ` And if you do not see r-x in the last triad you should make it.

Comment: `ls -l` on the dir where the .sh script is contained gives the following result: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 73 Nov 27 22:08 startPythonHTTPServer.sh`

Comment: @RomeoNinov Even giving the script the 777 rights did not help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running into the Jenkins Process Tree Killer.  Basically, when a build finishes, Jenkins kills any processes started by that build, even if those processes were moved to the background.

To stop processes from being killed, set the environment variable `BUILD_ID` to anything that doesn't contain the string `JENKINS`, for instance:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
```

If you are using Pipelines instead of Freestyle jobs, the official docs say to change the value of `JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE` instead, but I use Pipelines and haven't had any issues by altering only `BUILD_ID`.

More info in the [official docs](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller) and in [the same question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169457/how-to-tell-jenkins-not-to-kill-processes-after-successful-execution-of-job-in-m).